# Alpha gradient with geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the grid scatter plot below. For each species in each panel, I would like the smoothed line to reflect the density of the data.

My idea was to first cut the x axis values in bins and count the number of observation for each species for each sex in each year and use that count variable for `alpha`. But it doesn't seem to work (even when using `stat_smooth(geom= 'line'...)` ).

For example, in the bottom left panel (female, 2009), I would expect the line to be relatively more transparent between x values of 15 - 16, then darker between 16-18, and very transparent above 18.

Thanks

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
# Create a new variable for 
# binned values of bill_depth_mm
# for each species in each grid panel
penguins_cut <- penguins %>% 
  group_by(species, sex, year) %>% 
  mutate(xbin = cut(
    bill_depth_mm,
    breaks = 4 )) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Count the number of observations
count_data <- penguins_cut %>% 
  group_by(species, sex, year, xbin) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'species', 'sex', 'year'. You can override
#> using the `.groups` argument.

df <- left_join(penguins_cut,
                count_data,
                by = c("species", "sex", "year", "xbin"))

ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = bill_depth_mm, 
           y = bill_length_mm,
           colour = species)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(aes(alpha = count),
              geom='line', se=FALSE)+  
  facet_grid(year ~ sex)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Most ggplot2 geoms cannot vary in color/fill/alpha/linewidth/etc. within a series without either making them into separate pieces (e.g. geom_segment replacing geom_line) or using an external package like `ggforce` for `geom_link` etc. I don't know of a simple way to do either of those things with `geom_smooth`.

Comment: @JonSpring you're right, you can't do this in `geom_smooth` - it requires a `geom_segment` or `geom_link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky, but not impossible. You would need to precalculate the density and the smooth, then plot with `geom_segment`

The data wrangling would be something like

```r
df <- left_join(penguins_cut,
                count_data,
                by = c("species", "sex", "year", "xbin")) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))

smooth_df <- df %>%
  group_by(sex, species, year) %>%
  reframe(bill = density(bill_depth_mm, from = 13, to = 22)$x,
          density = density(bill_depth_mm, from = 13, to = 22)$y,
          bill_length_mm = predict(loess(bill_length_mm ~ bill_depth_mm,
                              control = loess.control(surface = "direct"),
                              span = 1),
                              newdata = bill)) %>%
  rename(bill_depth_mm = bill) %>%
  group_by(sex, species, year) %>%
  mutate(xend = lag(bill_depth_mm), 
         yend = lag(bill_length_mm),
         density = density / max(density))
```

And the plotting code would be:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = bill_depth_mm, 
           y = bill_length_mm,
           colour = species)) +
  geom_point(size = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(alpha = density, xend = xend, yend = yend), 
               data = smooth_df, linewidth = 1.5) +
  facet_grid(year ~ sex) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA)) +
  ylim(30, 60)
```

[image]

I'm not sure if this adds anything to the plot, but I guess it's kinda cool.

---

**Edit**

If `loess` is not appropriate for your data, you can use `gam` with a smoother. Here, for example, is how you would create the `smooth_df` object with `gam`:

```r
smooth_df <- df %>%
  group_by(sex, species, year) %>%
  reframe(bill = density(bill_depth_mm, from = 13, to = 22)$x,
          density = density(bill_depth_mm, from = 13, to = 22)$y,
          bill_length_mm = predict(
            mgcv::gam(bill_length_mm ~ s(bill_depth_mm, k = 8, bs = "cs")),
                      newdata = data.frame(bill_depth_mm = bill))) %>%
  rename(bill_depth_mm = bill) %>%
  group_by(sex, species, year) %>%
  mutate(xend = lag(bill_depth_mm), 
         yend = lag(bill_length_mm),
         density = density / max(density))
```

Using the same plotting code, this produces:

[image]

Comment: That's a very pretty result, nicely coded.

Comment: That looks great. Any chance you could add alternative smoothing options like splines for example? The goal is to do this with a very large dataset and loess isn't usable .

Comment: @CyG sure - you could use `gam` and fit whatever smoothers you like. See my update.