# Alpha gradient for geom_spline in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline

I have a large and complex dataframe.
I wish to fit a smoothed line. (loess isn't possible due to large data and gam doesn't look good). I have found geom_spline or stat_spline from the ggforumla package to work well.

I wish to adjust the transparency of the spline line based on the number of observation for a given bin (I used `cut`).

I have tried `stat_spline()` with a point geom but that doesn't affect the transparency.
Ideally the final plot would show a line with varying transparency based on the number of observations for the given group on the given x axis bin.

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggformula)

penguins_with_obs <- penguins %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(bill_depth_mm_cut = cut(bill_depth_mm, 10)) %>% 
  group_by(species, bill_depth_mm_cut) %>%
  mutate(obs = n()) %>% 
  arrange(bill_depth_mm_cut) %>% 
  ungroup()

ggplot(penguins_with_obs, aes(x = bill_depth_mm, 
               y = bill_length_mm,
               colour = species)) +
  facet_grid(species ~ sex) +
  geom_point(size = 1)+
  #geom_spline(aes(alpha = obs), df = 10)+
  stat_spline(aes(alpha = obs), df = 10, geom = "point", size = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You might have to compute the confidence intervals yourself (and/or retrieve them from `ggplot_build` and then add them with `geom_ribbon` with the `alpha` mapping set appropriately ...

Comment: My real dataframe has many more groups within each panel. To avoid overplotting I would prefer the splines to adjust for transparency rather than add ribbons.

Comment: How is this different from [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77455907/alpha-gradient-with-geom-smooth) @CyG? Is it just that you want a different smoothing algorithm?

Comment: +1 to @AllanCameron's question: it does seem like your answer might be in the updated version of your question. (When you have linked/an evolving series of questions like this one, it's definitely a good idea to explain what's different about the new question, and include links to the previous question in your new question so that people can see the context ...)

Comment: Apologies if too repetitive. I was hoping for a ggplot2 integrated response using a stat_* solution that would avoid the manual calculations. I will close this one if there's not integrated ggplot2 solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Would you try adding `alpha = obs` to `aes` section, please...

```
ggplot(penguins_with_obs,
   aes(x = bill_depth_mm,
       y = bill_length_mm,
       colour = species,
       alpha = obs)) +
     facet_grid(species ~ sex) +
     geom_point(size = 1) +
     geom_spline(aes(alpha = obs), df = 10) +
     stat_spline(aes(alpha = obs),
                 df = 10,
                 geom = "point",
                 size = 2)
```

Comment: I got a bunch of warnings (and no ribbons): "The following aesthetics were dropped during statistical transformation: alpha
ℹ This can happen when ggplot fails to infer the correct grouping structure in the data.
ℹ Did you forget to specify a `group` aesthetic or to convert a numerical variable into a factor?" (I think `alpha` is probably not allowed to be mapped in this context?)

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear. I want the spline to have alpha `aes` not the scatter points themselves. Hence why I tried with stat_spline and a point geom. Ideally I one would use the "segment" geom